# Angular 2 ZoneAwareError in Tutorial, but only for chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

Hello here and thanks for helping ! 
I'm performing the angular tutorial tour of heroes, and I have ended the point [4.Multiples Components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html), but the content does not load (we see "Loading AppComponent content here ...") and I have this error on chrome developper tools:

> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: (SystemJS) Invalid or unexpected token
>       SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>           at eval…, __zone_symbol__stack: "(SystemJS) Invalid or unexpected token↵    SyntaxErro…n.js↵    Error loading

I can't paste more because the error is displaying a very lot of information.
The real problem is here: At this point of the tutorial, my app work perfectly on edge and firefox... I don't understand what is wrong with chrome :/ ...

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more about your problem so users can understand more and help you!

Comment: I don't know how explain more, I have linked the tutorial with all the code. I have exactly the same code :/ ... And the entire error is too long ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's seem it's a problem with chrome browser cache... The bug appear at randomly moment, and I have to delete it integraly if I want to see my code working... 
I don't know why this error but that fix the problem. Sorry for this, and thanks.